# How to push props to component without any connection and calls? Another page

Tags: reactjs

How to push props to component without any connection and calls? Another page 
I have profile and company employees structure i wanna do button what will show to users theirs place in structure, but this is two pages without any render and connections or calls like `<OrgStructure employeeCode="test"/>`

Comment: The question is too vague. Where is your code? What have you tried? Stackoverflow is not a free coding service. Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please, provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reflects the problem you are facing.

Comment: also provide some tags

Answer (score 0):

If you have two Components that share common state but can't be directly coupled, you should use a global state container of whom both Components can read from.

You should check out https://react-redux.js.org/. It provides a global state container called "redux store". Components can independently subscribe to the store and get updated whenever the data in the store changes.